# InvalidCastException for generic type

Tags: c#

Please help me understand why this code throws InvalidCastException

```
class A {}

class Model<T> : A
{
    public TModel Copy<TModel> where TModel : Model<T>
    {
        var copy = new Model<T>();
        ...
        return (TModel) copy; //this line throws InvalidCastException
    }
}

class TestModel : Model<A> { }

...

//I cannot do this:
var model = new TestModel();
var copy = model.Copy<TestModel>();
```

Comment: `Model<T>` inherits `A` class and uses it a generic type parameter in `TestModel`. Why do you need to do so?

Comment: `Model<T>` is a supertype of `TModel` so you can't cast an instance to `TModel` for the same reason you can expect `(string)(new object())` to work.

Comment: Thank you @Lee makes perfect sense

Comment: You should be able to just return "copy" without casting it.